# Dynamic linking fails on CLang for constexpr static member of fully specialized template

Tags: c++, templates, clang, dynamic-linking, constexpr

Can anybody, please, *explain 1) why the code below does not work on CLang* and *2) how should it be rewritten to be compatible* with CLang?

```
using LinkWeight = float;

template <bool WEIGHTED=true>
struct InpLink {
    using Weight = LinkWeight;  //!< \copydoc LinkWeight
    Weight  weight;  //!< Link weight
    // ...
};

template <>
struct InpLink<false> {
    using Weight = LinkWeight;  //!< \copydoc LinkWeight
    constexpr static Weight  weight = 1;
};
```

This code works fine on GCC, but has the linking error on CLang 3.8.1 on Linux Ubuntu x64:

> undefined reference to `InpLink::weight'

After the definition:

```
template <>
constexpr typename InpLink<false>::Weight  InpLink<false>::weight;
```

the compile-time error is: `extraneous 'template<>' in declaration of variable 'weight'`

After the definition:

```
template <bool WEIGHTED>
constexpr typename InpLink<false>::Weight  InpLink<false>::weight;
```

the compile time error is:

```
..cluster.hpp:31:60: error: redefinition of 'weight' as different kind of symbol
constexpr typename InpLink<false>::Weight  InpLink<false>::weight;
                                                           ^
..cluster.h:58:27: note: previous definition is here
        constexpr static Weight  weight = 1;
```

Which looks like a CLang bug...

**NOTE:** The same example works fine on CLang if I have 2 parameters in the template, perform partial specialization and define the static constexpr weight as:

```
template <bool TMP>
constexpr typename InpLink<false, TMP>::Weight  InpLink<false, UNSIGNED>::weight;
```

Having

```
template <bool WEIGHTED=true, bool TMP=true>
struct InpLink {
    using Weight = LinkWeight;  //!< \copydoc LinkWeight
    Weight  weight;  //!< Link weight
    // ...
};

template <bool TMP>
struct InpLink<false, TMP> {
    using Weight = LinkWeight;  //!< \copydoc LinkWeight
    constexpr static Weight  weight = 1;
};
```

Obviously I don't want to use additional template parameter to overcome the linking error. Is there any other way to solve this?
What is wrong with CLang 3.8.1 or with my full template specialization?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, it seems this is a bug in CLang <= 3.8.1, which limits usage of constexpr for static members in dynamic libs and prevents separate definition of static members of the fully specialized templates.
And the way to overcome it is to:
1. Use static const instead of constexpr for CLang.
2. Define static member ONLY corresponding to the template declaration instead of the full specialization:

```
template <bool WEIGHTED=false>
struct InpLink {
    using Weight = LinkWeight;  //!< \copydoc LinkWeight

    //! Link is unweighted
    constexpr static bool  IS_WEIGHTED = false;
    //! \copydoc SimpleLink<Weight>::weight
    // ATTENTION: such complicated definition is required to overcome
    // the linking error on CLang
#ifdef __clang__
    const
#else
    constexpr
#endif // __clang__
    static Weight  weight
#ifndef __clang__
        = 1
#endif // !__clang__
    ;
    // ...
};

template <>
struct InpLink<true> {
    using Weight = LinkWeight;  //!< \copydoc LinkWeight
    Weight  weight;  //!< Link weight
    // ...
};
```

And define the static weight in .cpp not the header as:

```
#ifdef __clang__
// Note: Required by CLang for the linking
template <>
const InpLink<false>::Weight  InpLink<false>::weight = 1;
#endif  // __clang__
```

PS GCC is really a far better and much more reliable compiler than CLang for release builds (CLang still has some unique benefits for debugging).